# applying functions to groups in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to apply simple functions to groups in pandas. I have this dataframe which I can group by `type`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"id": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], "v": [1,2,3,4], "type": ["X", "Y", "Y", "Y"]}).set_index("id")
df.groupby("type").mean()  # gets the mean per type
```

I want to apply a function like `np.log2` only to the groups before taking the mean of each group. This does not work since `apply` is element wise and `type` (as well as potentially other columns in `df` in a real scenario) is not numeric:

```
# fails
df.apply(np.log2).groupby("type").mean()
```

is there a way to apply `np.log2` only to the groups prior to taking the mean? I thought `transform` would be the answer but the problem is that it returns a dataframe that does not have the original `type` columns:

```
df.groupby("type").transform(np.log2)
           v
id          
a   0.000000
b   1.000000
c   1.584963
d   2.000000
```

Variants like grouping and then applying do not work: `df.groupby("type").apply(np.log2)`. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: use ``applymap`` on a frame for an element-wise applyer (before grouping); if you want to do: ``df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: x.applymap(np.log2))``; better yet ``np.log2(df._get_numeric_data())``

Comment: The first proposal gives `('Not implemented for this type', u'occurred at index type')`. The second one works but it drops the `type`, so you can't group afterwards. `_get_numeric_data()` can't be used with groups I believe. So can't think of how to use the second one to apply `np.log2` to numeric data only and then group or group first and then apply only to groups

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `np.log2` cannot deal with the first column.  Instead, you need to pass just your numeric column.  You can do this as suggested in the comments, or define a `lambda`:

```
df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: np.mean(np.log2(x['v'])))
```

---

As per comments, I would define a function:

```
df['w'] = [5, 6, 7,8]

def foo(x):
     return x._get_numeric_data().apply(axis=0, func=np.log2).mean()

df.groupby('type').apply(foo)

#              v         w
# type                    
# X     0.000000  2.321928
# Y     1.528321  2.797439
```

Comment: I'd like to use something like `_get_numeric_data()` so that I don't have to compute which columns are numeric (there are several even though in the example there's only `v`). how can I use that with your solution? as in `df.groupby("type").(...something here?...)`?